# How do I compare all the column values based on the Partition by with ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a case where there are many rows for the same ID, I just wanted to know if there is any way to find out whether the given ID includes some specific value or not.

### Table 1

```
ID      Dept      Salary       Flag    Date 
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-01
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-02
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-03
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-04
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-05
2        HR        4000         N      2017-01-01
2        HR        4000         N      2017-01-02
2        HR        4000         Y      2017-01-03
2        HR        4000         N      2017-01-04
2        HR        4000         N      2017-01-05
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-08
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-09
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-10
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-11
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-12
4        Edu       4800         N      2017-02-10
4        Edu       4800         N      2017-02-11
4        Edu       4800         N      2017-02-12
4        Edu       4800         Y      2017-02-13
4        Edu       4800         N      2017-02-14
4        Edu       4800         N      2017-02-15
```

### Expected Result:

```
ID      Dept      Salary       Flag    Date 
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-01
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-02
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-03
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-04
1        IT        5000         N      2017-01-05

3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-08
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-09
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-10
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-11
3        Fin       4500         N      2017-01-12
```

As IT and Fin don't have Y flag, in any row, I just want this result to be displayed. Is there any way I can find out this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
select * from @mytable
where id in (
select 
id from @mytable
group by id
having SUM(case when flag='N' then 1 else 0 end) =COUNT(*))
```

Comment: Thank you @ganesh, it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DENSE_RANK()` function to allow ranking based on column `Dept`, `Flag`

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE ID IN
(
       SELECT A.ID FROM 
       (
          SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (order by Dept, Flag) [RN] FROM <table>
       ) A GROUP BY A.ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT RN) = 1)
```

**EDIT** : If don't want to use of `DENSE_RANK()` function you could also use of simple `case` expression condition

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID FROM <table> GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Flag = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
);
```

Other simple way :

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM <table> WHERE FLAG ='Y'
);
```

Result :

```
ID  Dept    Salary  Flag        Date
1   IT      5000    N           2017-01-01
1   IT      5000    N           2017-01-02
1   IT      5000    N           2017-01-03
1   IT      5000    N           2017-01-04
1   IT      5000    N           2017-01-05
3   Fin     4500    N           2017-01-08
3   Fin     4500    N           2017-01-09
3   Fin     4500    N           2017-01-10
3   Fin     4500    N           2017-01-11
3   Fin     4500    N           2017-01-12
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it sample like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT ID FROM table WHERE FLAG ='Y'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution, this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Flaggen AS 
(
select distinct ID
from Table1
where Flag <> 'Y'
)

select * 
from Table1 
join Flaggen 
on Flaggen.Id = Table1.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey @Avi as you only want to display the records from the table just use where clause with id then u will get the output as expected

```
select id,Dept,Salary,Flag,Date 
from mytable
where id in (1,3)
```

Hope tis might help.